# Regex for parsing queryString

Tags: java, regex

Hi am looking for an Regular Expression which parses QueryString.Am using the below regex:

```
Pattern pr1=Pattern.compile("[\\?&](?<name>[^&=]+)=(?<value>[^&=]+)");
```

But its throwing

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 18
[\?&](?<name>[^&=]+)=(?<value>[^&=]+)
                  ^
```

Can anyone help me on

Comment: Regex used is"[\\?&](?<name>[^&=]+)=(\\?<value>[^&=]+)"

Comment: Can someone help me its urgent

Comment: Are you sure that you're using Java 7 / JDK 1.7? Because it looks like the regex-engine isn't recognizing the named capture-group notation.

Comment: doing this without a regex is (I think) a lot more clear and straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with `"%5b^&=%5d+">`. Sounds like it's complaining about the `>`. This can help: http://stevenbenner.com/2010/03/javascript-regex-trick-parse-a-query-string-into-an-object/

Answer (score 6):

Java <1.7 doesn't support named groups so change your regex to:

```
Pattern pr1 = Pattern.compile("[\\?&]([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)");
```

and then from the Matcher, get group # 1 and # 2 for the name and value.

**Update:**

```
String str =
        "http://test.abc.com/test/http/com/google/www/:/?code=1234&Id=123354455656%22";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[\\?&]([^&=]+)=([^&=]+)");
Matcher m = pt.matcher(str);
if (m.find())
    System.out.printf("name=[%s], value=[%s]%n", m.group(1), m.group(2));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
name=[code], value=[1234]
```

Comment: StringBuffer str1=new StringBuffer("http://test.abc.com/test/http/com/google/www/:/?code=1234&Id=123354455656");

Comment: My url goes like the above one.can u help me.am getting an error as match not found

Answer (score 0):

Lookbehind expressions must look for a fixed length string. You cannot use regex features such as * ? + inside lookbehind assertions.
`(?<name>[^&=]+)` is a lookbehind denoted by '?<' and it contains a '+'. Maybe you wanted to comment out the '<'?